# Grunt contrib coffee minify option

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

Is they anyway to generate directly minified js ? I don't want to use an other command such as grunt uglify because the sourcemaps won't point to the coffee but to the js

Answer (score 3):

I get what you're saying about the sourcemaps, but you can still use uglify in a chain that gets you what you want. Uglify can have the final sourcemaps point to the original coffee files using its sourceMapIn option:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    coffee: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true // causes creation of landing.js.map
        },
        files: { 'src/landing.js': 'src/landing.coffee' }
    },
    uglify: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            sourceMapIn: 'src/landing.js.map'
        },
        files: { 'src/landing.min.js': ['src/landing.js'] }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, sorry.

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee/issues/102

If your purpose is to debug server-side code, try running the app using the `coffee` binary instead of compiling it to JS and starting with `node`.